# Enable USB smartcard inside VMware

Tags: linux, vmware, smartcard

I am running Windows 7 inside VMWare Player on a Linux host.  I want to use a USB smart card reader but it is not working.  The client app reports: "**No Card Detected**", but it appears to recognize that the "reader" is connected and working.  The Windows driver "Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)" also reports "This device is working properly".

I had this setup working (with the same virtual machine) on an earlier version of Linux and with an earlier VMWare Player.  At that time, I had used the following addition to the .vmx file to get things working:

```
uhci.syncWriteback = "TRUE"
usb.generic.skipsetconfig = "TRUE"
usb.generic.allowCCID = "TRUE"
```

After a new Linux install, including new VMware Player, I can no longer use my smart card with the Windows 7 virtual machine.  **Is there a new trick to get this working?**

### version notes

Working versions:

- Distro: Linux Mint 10 Julia
- Kernel: 2.6.35-28-generic (64-bit)
- Player: 3.1.2 (corresponds to Workstation 7.1.2?)

Non working versions:

- Distro: Linux Mint 14 Nadia, 3.5.0-28-generic (64-bit)
- Distro: Linux Mint 15 Olivia, 3.8.0-25-generic (64-bit)
- Player: 4.0.6-1035888.x86_64
- Player: 5.0.2-1031769.x86_64
- Player: 3.1.6-744570.x86_64 (was unable to install due to kernel version)

It isn't clear whether this problem was introduced by the kernel change or by the VMware change.

### Host access test (Linux-side)

```
$ sudo openct-control init

[ ~ ]
$ sudo openct-tool wait
Card detected

[ ~ ]
$ sudo openct-control status
No.   Name                         Info
===================================================
  0   CCID Compatible              slot0: card present
```

The following command reports failure, but interestingly, turns on the green light.

```
$ sudo openct-tool read
Detected CCID Compatible
Card present, status changed
failed to read memory card: Operation not supported
```

*Follow up: I got identical results when running this test in a Linux client (3.0.0-16-generic).*

### Things to try

- Test openct utility as Linux guest [done]
- Use VirtualBox
- Contact technical support: [ActivKey on LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/company/actividentity/actividentity-activkey-sim-usb-token-545836/product), [HID Globalenter link description here](http://www.hidglobal.com)

### Alternatives

- Use a dedicated second computer just for VPN -- with access to a file-share (or USB drive)
- Setup VPN directly from Linux (host or guest)
- Install a Linux distro with the old kernel (Mint 9)

Comment: Are you using a ClientWare/Middleware ( i.e. ActivClient ) of any kind?

Comment: @Ramhound: My client app is "ActivClient".  When I insert my device (with embedded "card"), ActiveClient's status switches from "Card reader not detected" to "No Card Detected".

Comment: What device are you using exactly? Would also be helpful to know which version of ActivClient your using. I often have to do the old "Nintendo Cartiage" trick on my card reader. Of course I am ActivClient within a Virtual Machine but it shouldn't make a difference. Have you tried the native Windows 7 supoprt by chance?  If this is a DoD issued SmartCard the native support will work for all branches.

Comment: @Ramhound: My device is "Actividentity ACTIVKEY SIM 48010-C MAY09".  It looks pretty-much like [this](https://www.hidglobal.com/products/cards-and-credentials/identity-assurance/usb-tokens).  I interpret the "Nintendo Cartridge" trick to mean "blow the dust out" -- I really don't think that is the problem -- this device works fine in another computer.  I don't know what you mean by "native Windows 7 support", but my system seems to be using a Microsoft driver -- running the ActivClient app appears to be optional.

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows 8 has the capability to handle everything that ActivClient does. Have you tried without the middleware software installed to see if it will work. I would consider the product you linked to be a smart card reader, more of a secure token device, since it can't actually read smart cards ( based on the picture ).  Since it has no detector lights I have no other advice I can give.

Comment: I have attempted this with the ActivClient software both closed and uninstalled -- this seems to have no effect on my ability to use the key.

Comment: @Ramhound makes a good point: there is no "smart card" per se.  This device is a "SIM token" which (I believe) functions as a reader with a built-in card.  It is befuddling that, since **the card cannot be removed**, the error message that I get from ActivClient is "**No Card Detected**" -- even though it has no complaints about its ability to communicate with the "card reader".  *There must be some layer of complexity interfering with the driver*, probably either in the Linux kernel or in the VMware software -- the Windows VM previously worked, before I moved it to a new workstation.

Comment: Can you try a even newer version of Workstation by chance?  I was going to try this at home but I don't have that type of smart card reader.  Lets just call it that since we both know what you are trying to do :-)

Comment: @Ramhound: I just downloaded and tested the newest VMware Player (5.0.2) today.  I'm not using "VMware Workstation".  Thanks for helping!

Comment: I apologize I of course meant `VMWare Player` .  I dragged that into my head because of your own Workstation 7.1.2 reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solution with editing `.wmx` worked for me.
I'm on Ubuntu 22 with VMware 16!

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue answered in the following KB: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2000350&plainview=true

1. in linux terminal issue lsusb commend to see what the vendor and product id of your smart card reader
2. Open your .vmx file in a text editor
3. Add this line, replacing  and  with the values you found earlier:
   usb.quirks.device0 = "0x:0x allow" 
   Example: For the Apple device found in step 2, this line is:
   usb.quirks.device0 = "0x05ac:0x8240 allow"
4. Save and close the .vmx file.

Comment: Thanks for the post!  Hopefully I'll get around to testing your suggestion sometime soon.